# Android - Unable to get the latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, android-studio, location

Why I can not get the latitude and longitude?
I have check the permission. where is the problem?

```
public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView image_map;
    private Context mcontext = MapLocationActivity.this;
    static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_location);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        getLocation();

        image_map = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_map);

        image_map.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        image_map.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


                        View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.image_map);
                        StaticMap map = new StaticMap()
                                .center(new StaticMap.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude))
                                .size(v.getWidth() / 2, v.getHeight() / 2)
                                .zoom(18)
                                .scale(2).marker(new StaticMap.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude));
                        try {
                            Picasso.with(mcontext)
                                    .load(String.valueOf(map.toURL()))
                                    .into(image_map);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        }
                        image_map.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                });
    }

    void getLocation(){

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String [] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }else{
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location !=null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();

            }else{

                Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to find location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResult){
       super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResult);
       switch (requestCode){
           case REQUEST_LOCATION:
               getLocation();
               break;
       }
    }
}
```

---

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.root.a1718_it114105_b2_mayihelpyoumum.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.weaverprojects.gpstest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login" />
    <activity android:name=".DhMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainAdminActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".location" />
    <activity android:name=".Register" />
    <activity android:name=".employerRegister" />
    <activity android:name=".dhResetPassword" />
    <activity android:name=".addReceipt" />
    <activity android:name=".viewToDoList" />
    <!-- <activity android:name=".manageToDoList"></activity> -->
    <activity android:name=".editToDoList" />
    <activity android:name=".addToDoList" />
    <activity android:name=".showRemovedToDoList" />
    <activity android:name=".createTodoList" />
    <activity android:name=".dailyworkTodoList" />
    <activity android:name=".shoppingTodoList" />
    <activity android:name=".ChatStartActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChatMainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatRegisterActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ChatStartActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatLoginActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ChatStartActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChatSettingsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatStatusActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ChatSettingsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatUsersActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ChatMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChatProfileActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.smartyway.smartchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ChatMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".locationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AndroidGPSTrackingActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MapLocationActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

and I saw this.

W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.

Comment: `where is the problem?` Well you should exactly tell us where you have a problem. Exactly. Then we might be able to help you.

Comment: just i want to get the longitude and latitude, nothing to show me why i cant get the current location!

Comment: Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), rework your problem into something we can actually work with, and repost.

Comment: Why the  "location" is null?